# if statement with multiple command block in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, window, 32-bit

I am new to batch scripting and have been working with simple IF-ELSE statements. But when I use a block of multiple commands in IF condition, only the first command is skipped the other commands are executed. I cannot understand this behavior. If the condition is false, it should skip the entire command block and execute else part. Am I missing something? Here is my script:

```
@echo off
REM Beginning of the Script
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)" ( 
    echo 64-bit Windows... 
    echo 2nd line
    echo 3rd line 
) ELSE ( 
    echo 32-bit Windows...
)
```

The output on a 32-bit machine is:

```
2nd line
3rd line
32-bit Windows...
```

Comment: I just ran it in my XP mode VM and your example script works perfectly, echoing *only* `32-bit Windows...`.  Are you sure you aren't prematurely closing the parentheses in your production script?  FWIW, traditionally batch scripts use `if defined PROGRAMFILES(x86)` to test the bitness of Windows.  Your script as-is would echo `32-bit Windows...` no matter what.  In 64-bit Windows, there's a space between `Files` and `(x86)` in the directory name.  No space in the environment variable name, though, if you want to switch to `if defined`.

Comment: And use `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` as otherwise you create two local copies of entire environment table instead of just one.

Comment: Batch files do not support else statements. You need a second if statement matching your requirements.

Comment: `IF [NOT] condition (command) ELSE (command)` is valid syntax pattern. @RandyRakestraw you are wrong. See [windows command line reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can chain commands with & (or && and || if you expect different behaviors based on result from previous commands).

One liners:

```
if "1" == "1" (echo wait! & echo is it really true?) else (echo oops & echo sorry, that's false)
```

```
if "0" == "1" (echo wait! & echo is it really true?) else (echo oops & echo sorry, that's false)
```

Hopefully there are better ways to achieve what you want. This one at least works.